Difference of OPE in "Conformal Field Theory" and "Introduction to Conformal Field Theory With Applications to String Theory"
The two books "Conformal Field Theory"("CFT" for short, in section 6.6.3) and "Introduction to Conformal Field Theory With Applications to String Theory"("Intro" for short, in section 2.6.3) both give the OPE of two primary operators from the coefficients of 3-point correlators. I'll try to rephrase their arguments:
The setting is almost the same: for each conformal dimension $h,\bar h$ there is a finite set of primary fields $\phi_i,\,i=1,\dots$. such that $$\left<\phi_i(w,\bar w)\phi_j(z,\bar z)\right>=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{(w-z)^{2h}(\bar w-\bar z)^{2\bar h}}$$.
And in "Intro" only chiral field are considered, i.e. $\bar h=0$.
In "Intro" they assume that the OPE has the following form:
$$\phi_i(z)\phi_j(0)=\sum_l\sum_n C\partial^n\phi_l(0)$$
Where $C$ is a scalar relevant to $i,j,l,n$ and some power of $z$ to balance the scaling dimension.
And in "CFT" the OPE has the following form: $$\phi_i(z)\phi_j(0)=\sum_l\sum_{k,\bar k}C\phi^{k,\bar k}_l(0)$$. Here $k,\bar k$ is a multiple index: $k=(k_0,\dots,k_n)$ and $\phi^{k,\bar k}_l(0):=L_{-k_0}\dots L_{-k_n}\bar L_{-\bar k_0}\dots \bar L_{-\bar k_{\bar n}}\phi_l(0)$. Again $C$ is a scalar relevant to $i,j,l,k,\bar k$ and some power of $z,\bar z$ to balance the scaling dimension.
So here we can see the discrepancies: why do we believe the basis of operators in OPE is $\partial^n\phi_l(0)$ or $\phi^{k,\bar k}_l(0)$? They can not be both correct as they have different dimension ($n$ and $p(n)$).

Which authors? Which eqs?

I've basically figure out why they are different: In "Intro" they are considering quasi-primary field, which is a larger space, and those together with partial derivatives, i.e. $L_{-1}$ generates the same linear space with the span of primary field with action of $L_{-n}$s.
And it would be an interesting question of which (linear combination) of descendant fields are quasi-primary. I'm not sure about the followings:
A field $\phi$ is quasi-primary iff $L_0\left|\phi\right>=h\left|\phi\right>$ and $L_1\left|\phi\right>=0$. Say if $\phi$ is primary with conformal dimension $h$, then consider level 2 descendants, which are linear combination of $L_{-1}^2\left|\phi\right>$ and $L_{-2}\left|\phi\right>$:
$$L_1L_{-1}^2\left|\phi\right>=(L_{-1}^2L_1+4L_{-1}L_0+2L_{-1})\left|\phi\right>=(4h+2)L_{-1}\left|\phi\right>$$
$$L_1L_{-2}\left|\phi\right>=(L_{-2}L_1+3L_{-1})\left|\phi\right>=3L_{-1}\left|\phi\right>$$
So $L_{-1}^2\phi-\frac{3}{4h+2}L_{-2}\phi$ is quasi-primary.
